# IF Else statement not properly worked in setInterval() function while creating count-down timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

Even after adding if else statment inside setInterval() function to clear the interval once my time variable reaches 0, the setInterval() is still running with negative time value.

Please specify what the problem is and provide some solution for the same.

Here is my code for count-down timer component:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export const Timer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10000);
  const [pause, setPause] = useState(false);
  let timerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {  
    startTimer();
  
    return () => clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }, []);

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    setPause(true);
  };

  const startTimer = () => {
    setPause(false);
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (time <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timerRef.current);
        setPause(true);
      }
      else{
        setTime((prevTime) => prevTime - 1000);
      }
    }, 1000);

  };

  const getFormattedText = (time) => {
    const SECONDS = 1000;
    const MINUTES = 60 * SECONDS;
    const HOURS = 60 * MINUTES;
    const DAYS = 24 * HOURS;

    const days = Math.floor(time / DAYS);
    const hours = Math.floor((time % DAYS) / HOURS);
    const minutes = Math.floor((time % HOURS) / MINUTES);
    const seconds = Math.floor((time % MINUTES) / SECONDS);

    return (
      <div className="countdown-timer">
        {days < 10 ? `0${days}` : days} : {hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours} :{" "}
        {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes} :{" "}
        {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      {getFormattedText(time)}
      <div>
        <button onClick={pause ? startTimer : stopTimer}>
          {!pause ? "Stop" : "Start"} Timer
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

Here is the output after 0 second:

[This is the link for Output's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv91N.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` inside your `startTimer` is receiving only a static value of `time` - the initial `10000` stays as it is. Even if you `setTime`, the updated `time` is only reflected outside the `setInterval` and not within, because `setInterval` executes on its own scope and context. So the `else` part is executed always, giving you negative values.

To fix, you will need a `useEffect` that will respond to the change due to `setTime` Replace your `startTimer` method with the below code,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(time);
  if (time <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    setPause(true);
  }
}, [time]);

const startTimer = () => {
  if (time > 0) {
    setPause(false);
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevTime) => prevTime - 1000);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

your initial `startTimer` callback is split into using `useEffect` wherein it can listen and respond to change in state `time` due to `setTime`. Please refer https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#updating-state-based-on-previous-state-from-an-effect for further refinement of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the closure created for the time state inside the
setInterval() callback. When your setInterval() function is set up, it
captures the value of time at that moment, and subsequent updates to
time aren't reflected within that closure.

```
const startTimer = () => {
  setPause(false);
  timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
    setTime((prevTime) => {
      if (prevTime <= 1000) { 
        clearInterval(timerRef.current);
        setPause(true);
        return 0; 
      }
      return prevTime - 1000;
    });
  }, 1000);
};
```

The current state of time is always checked against 0 correctly,
preventing it from going negative. The interval is cleared correctly
when the time reaches 0 or less. The setPause(true) action is
correctly called within the context where prevTime is guaranteed to be
the latest value of time.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bw9ag8?file=src%2FApp.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const getNewValue = (currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue <= 0) {
    return currentValue;
  }
  return currentValue - 1000;
};

const getFormattedText = (time) => {
  const SECONDS = 1000;
  const MINUTES = 60 * SECONDS;
  const HOURS = 60 * MINUTES;
  const DAYS = 24 * HOURS;

  const days = Math.floor(time / DAYS);
  const hours = Math.floor((time % DAYS) / HOURS);
  const minutes = Math.floor((time % HOURS) / MINUTES);
  const seconds = Math.floor((time % MINUTES) / SECONDS);

  return (
    <div className="countdown-timer">
      {days < 10 ? `0${days}` : days} : {hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours} :{' '}
      {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes} :{' '}
      {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const timeRef = useRef(10000);
  const isStopRef = useRef(false);
  const intervalRef = useRef();
  const [_, toggleRender] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!intervalRef.current) {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        if (isStopRef.current === true) {
          return;
        }

        timeRef.current = getNewValue(timeRef.current);
        toggleRender((o) => !o);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{getFormattedText(timeRef.current)}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          isStopRef.current = false;
        }}
      >
        startttt
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          isStopRef.current = true;
        }}
      >
        stopppp
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          isStopRef.current = false;
          timeRef.current = 10000;
        }}
      >
        reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you click event is likely automatically firing

```
<button onClick={() => {pause ? startTimer : stopTimer}}>
```